# Creating and updating a Pootle project via REST API with Slumber

Tags: python, rest, tastypie, pootle

Does anyone have a working example of how to create and update a [Pootle](http://pootle.translatehouse.org/) project and its template strings via Pootle's [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/)-based REST API?  I would really like to see a minimal, elegant way to do this with, for example, [Slumber](https://github.com/samgiles/slumber).

My case:  I would like to create several Pootle projects from my Web application.  You can think of each such project as corresponding to one article in a collection of articles in a Web service.  For each of these projects, I would need to be able to

1. create it initially with a list of extracted (template) strings (through the API),
2. provide actual translations (human, through Pootle's Web interface [*not* a problem]),
3. retrieve translations, ideally as PO file through the API, and
4. update the set of translatable strings (through API), so that a human can perform more translations.

I've read Pootle's [Glossary](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/developers/glossary.html), [API definition](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/api/index.html), [its API usage notes](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/api/using.html), the [Tastypie documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/), and the [Slumber documentation](http://slumber.readthedocs.org/), but feel like there's a part I'm missing.  For example, Tastypie offer great options to specify filtering parameters in the request URL, but I get the feeling I have to retrieve the whole list of projects to search for the right one in the app, which makes me wonder how others are using the API.

The following code correctly creates a new project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import slumber

api = slumber.API('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/', auth=('admin', 'admin'))

project_data = {
    'code': 'test01',
    'fullname': 'Test #01',
    'description': 'Another test.',
    'source_language': '/api/v1/languages/2/',
    'translation_projects': [],
}

new_project = api.projects.post(project_data)
```

And `new_project` refers to the following dict:

```
{'backlink': 'http://localhost:8000/projects/test01/',
 'checkstyle': 'standard',
 'code': 'test01',
 'description': '<p>Another test.</p>',
 'fullname': 'Test #01',
 'ignoredfiles': u'',
 'localfiletype': 'po',
 'resource_uri': '/api/v1/projects/10/',
 'source_language': '/api/v1/languages/2/',
 'translation_projects': [],
 'treestyle': 'auto'}
```

Given that I keep, for example, the `code` value for later. What is the most efficient way of retrieving the project's `id` (which is `10`, from the `resource_uri`)?  The reason I want that, is for later requests, like:

```
api.projects(10).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Curling](http://curling.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)? It is a library wrapping Slumber, that specifically targets Django Tastypie APIs. It provides methods like `by_url()` that translates URLs like `/generic/transaction/8/` to `generic.transaction(8)`.

Comment: That looks useful.  I'll look into it, but after a first glance on Curling's requirements, it seems to require an awful lot for a client library, including Django itself and a PyJWT-mozilla, which in turn requires M2Crypto that depends on Swig during its build.

Comment: And, even if `by_url()` looks nice, slumber already supports the syntax `api.get('/api/v1/projects/10/').get()`, which in my example above would correspond to `api.get(new_project['resource_uri']).get()`.

Comment: Actually, I've now discovered that the slumber API object accepts any attribute name, so even `api.by_uri('/api/v1/projects/10/').get()` works.  ;)

Comment: Agreed, those are some heavy requirements.

Comment: After wasting too many hours on trying to get Pootle behave appropriately, I guess the answer is really to use another translation server, like [Weblate](http://weblate.org/).